# Moving PC to different network, different IP range

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have a thin client on my home network running ubuntu server 20.04. The pc gets an IP from DHCP server in the 192.168.1.X range. I have a DHCP reservation on the router so this stays the same.

I want to move this PC to another location where the DHCP server assigns IPs in the 192.168.8.X range. Incidentally, both routers are Huawei B525, the only difference is the IP range.

I tried to do this today, but the PC would not get an IP from the router (or rather the router would not assign an IP to the PC). I tried setting a static IP in the netplan .yml file in the 192.168.8.X range, but this did not work either. So I reverted back to DHCP.

Is there any reason why the PC would get a DHCP address from 192.168.1.X and not 192.168.8.X? I'd rather not have to change the IP range of the second location, as I don't see why this is happening, and doing so would require me to change multiple other DHCP reservations, and other local LAN services.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Who controls the network in the second location? You may want to check that the second location is not filtering or assigning IPs based on MAC addresses 

Comment: "So I reverted back to DHCP." What IP address did you get by DHCP? `ip a`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it is not problem of your PC, but the DHCP server or network in second location.

### Possible problems:

1. The DHCP scope in second location is exhausted.
2. The DHCP server in second location assigns addresses only to clients having static reservations.
3. There exists network problem (interface, cable, switch port...) which is not related to DHCP.
4. A security feature like 802.1X is activated in second location. Only authenticated devices can connect to the LAN.

The possibility #3 or #4 is most likely, because you cannot communicate even you use static address.

### Diagnosis

Try these diagnosis steps:

- Connect another device to LAN in second location by the same way you use for PC and check whether it gets IP address.
- Use the Wireshark (or tshark, tcpdump) started in your PC having issue. Check packets during the DHCP communication. Watch if you see any UDP packets having port 67 or 68 (usual correct sequence is DHCP discover, offer, request, acknowledgement...). Use display filter `bootp` eventually `udp.port==67 or udp.port==68` in Wireshark.  Some [details about DHCP sequence are here](https://www.netmanias.com/en/post/techdocs/5998/dhcp-network-protocol/understanding-the-basic-operations-of-dhcp). The DHCP server must responds to the client discover packet and the offer response must include right IP address from DHCP scope (192.168.8.x).